# Loop with two counters

Tags: loops, sas

Following is some C code. How do I do the same in sas?

```
 For(i=30, j=1; i<=41, j<=12; i++, j++)
    (
    closure(i,j) /*calling function with input parameters I and j */
    );
```

I basically want to do the following macro calls using a loop with two counters I and J

```
%closure(30,201201);
%closure(31,201202);
%closure(32,201203);
%closure(33,201204);
%closure(34,201205);
%closure(35,201206);
%closure(36,201207);
%closure(37,201208);
%closure(38,201209);
%closure(39,201210);
%closure(40,201211);
%closure(41,201212);
```

Please note that I do not want to use a nested loop. 
Tips are appreciated.

Comment: Vague subject line is unlikely to be helpful to future visitors with the same question. You didn't even tag the question [sas]!

Comment: See [loops in sas](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/09/07/loops-in-sas/) and then `Variations on the DO loop: DO WHILE and DO UNTIL`

Answer (score 2):

Doing this in SAS depends on how your data is structured.  It's possible to do this:

```
%do i = 1 to 12;
  %closure(%eval(29+i),%eval(201200+i));
%end;
```

That's a bit odd, but it should work fine.

You could also do it in the %closure macro.  Pass i and then determine the value of the other parameters inside the macro, if they always have this relationship.  If they always have *some* relationship, but the 2012 and 18 parts are variable, then you have several options:

**Define 2012 and 29 as macro variables ahead of this step, and replace them in the code with such.**

```
%let year=2012;
%let startrec=29;
%do i = 1 to 12;
  %closure(%eval(&startrec.+&i.),%eval(&year.00+&i.));
%end;
```

**Use date functions to determine the value of j, if it is not always 01-12.**

```
%closure(30,%sysfunc(intnx(month,'01JUN2011'd,&i.-1)))
```

(you may want to format the result in YYYYMM format, or you may be just as well off using the date result, depending on %closure)

**Define all of these terms in a dataset, and call the macro from the dataset.**

```
data to_call;
input i j;
datalines;
30 201201
31 201202
.... ; 
run;

proc sql;
 select cats('%closure(',i,',',j,')') into :calllist separated by ' ' from to_call;
quit;

&calllist.
```

That's a more 'SAS'sy way to do things, making the process data driven.  Most commonly used when the i and j parameters are stored as data element somewhere (in a control table, for example, or derived from some other data source).

Answer (score 1):

So If you want

- %closure(30,201201);
- %closure(31,201202);
- %closure(32,201203);
- %closure(33,201204);
- %closure(34,201205);
- %closure(35,201206);
- %closure(36,201207);
- %closure(37,201208);
- %closure(38,201209);
- %closure(39,201210);
- %closure(40,201211);
- %closure(41,201212);

then it would be better either you calculate the value of J and bring it to 201200 aur something near about.
Or you should start the j loop with 201201 and end it to 201212
simply go for

For(i=30, j=201201; i<=41, j<=201212; i++, j++)

(

```
  closure(i,j)
```

);